# Android Studio Emulator error (Upgrade to Chipmunk)

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I upgraded Android Studio to Chipmunk release. After the upgrade I am not able to connect to emulator. I did not change any settings with AVD and migrated it from the previously working version.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks